# Using MD5() in SELECT Query does not return results

Tags: mysql, md5

I have this query in my Laravel PHP application, however, I found out that this problem primarily relates to MySQL rather than Laravel or PHP.  This is the query:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE MD5('email')='9e1af6d8046e217984ea76bf489a64eb' AND password_md5='f3617237ac21562663a40608a85ea38d';
```

I'm only given the email's md5 hash as well as the password (also md5-hashed) and need to retrieve the user's `id` from the `MySQL` database. `email` in the database is **not** hashed, that's why I found that I need to `MD5()` it during the statement. However, the above query does not return any results when it should have returned one. **Yes, I made sure that the hashes are properly input**.

What I found when trying to tackle this problem was that `SELECT MD5('users.email')` does not return the same MD5 hash as the actual email address. I wonder whether I'm misusing the `MD5()` function or if MySQL adds anything to it so the hash is different from the one also calculated my PHP.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around `email` if is a column identifier

Comment: Wow. This is it. Please, post this as an answer so I'll tick it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the password "klavier" :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, and I'm aware that this needs to be more secured. :-)

Comment: @JohnConde what exactly is MySQL trying or doing when having `email` in quotes?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Nope, using md5 is totally fine. Just not for hashing passwords. Just use the algorithm for what it has been intended for.

Comment: Because off the rainbow tables you should not use MD5/SHA1 for passwords anny more. make use off PHP's password_hash with BCRYPT algoritme. password_hash generates hashes that can't you used in a rainbow table because the hash generated changes every  time demo ( http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99e3b80556136b80b486d1ed9d5c3ed31ead2e2b ) you need to use password_verify to verify the hash... Plus MD5 is a fast hashing algoritme that can be implemented on the GPU software very well to bruteforce the hash, BCRYPT is designed to be slow even on GPU's

Comment: @Doe MySQL is assuming you mean the literal string "email" not the column identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `email` if it is a column identifier. You only need to use quotes for string literals.

```
 SELECT id FROM users WHERE MD5(email)='9e1af6d8046e217984ea76bf489a64eb' AND password_md5='f3617237ac21562663a40608a85ea38d';
```